# How to Label y-axis properly when plot from CSV file?

Tags: pgfplots, csv, tikz-datavisualization

I would like labeling as follows:
[image]

It does not get proper labeling on y-axis when I am plotting data from CSV file in Latex. Here is the code :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}


\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={\,}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
%restrict x to domain=1:4,
restrict y to domain=7:8, %ymax=8,ymin=7
xtick={1,2,3,4},
%ytick={7.90,7.91,...,7.99,8},
xlabel=Shares, ylabel=Entropy]


\addplot[color=red,mark=*, mark size=1.5pt] table[x=Share_No., y=Entropy_r, col sep=tab]{data.csv};
\addplot[color=green,mark=square*, mark size=1.5pt] table[x=Share_No., y=Entropy_g, col sep=tab]{data.csv};
\addplot[color=blue,mark=triangle*, mark size=1.5pt] table[x=Share_No., y=Entropy_b, col sep=tab]{data.csv};
\legend{red,green, blue}
 \end{axis} 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and the CSV file :

```
Share_No.   Entropy_r   Entropy_g   Entropy_b
1   7.9981486429    7.99831760161   7.99844751811
2   7.99870797699   7.99858499663   7.99867850346
3   7.99883018839   7.99864575932   7.99835839694
4   7.99851352793   7.99834080804   7.99864899695
```

It produces the following graph:

[image]

How can I fix this?

**Updated:** The answer in the given link is not working for me.  Here are the modified codes:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}


\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={\,}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
    y tick label style={
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    fixed,
    fixed zerofill,
    precision=1,
    /tikz/.cd
},

%restrict x to domain=1:4,
%restrict y to domain=7:8, %ymax=8,ymin=7
xtick={1,2,3,4},
%ytick={7.90,7.91,...,7.99,8},
xlabel=Shares, ylabel=Entropy]

\addplot[color=red,mark=*, mark size=1.5pt] table[x=Share_No., y=Entropy_r, col sep=tab]{data.csv};
\addplot[color=green,mark=square*, mark size=1.5pt] table[x=Share_No., y=Entropy_g, col sep=tab]{data.csv};
\addplot[color=blue,mark=triangle*, mark size=1.5pt] table[x=Share_No., y=Entropy_b, col sep=tab]{data.csv};
\legend{red,green, blue}
 \end{axis} 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @engineer The answer in the given ling is not working. I have tried with this code.

Comment: Not working is unfortunately no measurable criterion. Could you please be more specific what does not work? Otherwise, this seems to be a duplicate…

Comment: @TeXnician I have added the modified code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer linked to works just fine, but you didn't set the closing `]` correctly (after your post's update you introduced a `\par` within the options which is causing another error).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
Share_No.   Entropy_r   Entropy_g   Entropy_b
1   7.9981486429    7.99831760161   7.99844751811
2   7.99870797699   7.99858499663   7.99867850346
3   7.99883018839   7.99864575932   7.99835839694
4   7.99851352793   7.99834080804   7.99864899695
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={\,}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
%restrict x to domain=1:4,
%restrict y to domain=7:8, %ymax=8,ymin=7
xtick={1,2,3,4},
%ytick={7.90,7.91,...,7.99,8},
xlabel=Shares, ylabel=Entropy,
    y tick label style={
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    fixed,
    fixed zerofill,
    precision=3,
    /tikz/.cd
}]
\addplot[color=red,mark=*, mark size=1.5pt] table[x=Share_No., y=Entropy_r, col sep=space]{data.csv};
\addplot[color=green,mark=square*, mark size=1.5pt] table[x=Share_No., y=Entropy_g, col sep=space]{data.csv};
\addplot[color=blue,mark=triangle*, mark size=1.5pt] table[x=Share_No., y=Entropy_b, col sep=space]{data.csv};
\legend{red,green, blue}
 \end{axis} 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```